# SQL Server Temp Table of Sequential Integers As Lookup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a temporary table that has sequential integer values from 1 to 1,000 for use as a LEFT JOIN on my table that has the following sub-set of records:

```
USRNO   EVSTRING
1       John Doe
10      Jane Doe
13      Jason Doe
16      Jeremy Doe
```

I'm attempting to identify the user numbers (USRNO) that do NOT appear in the records returned above (ie: find the missing user numbers).

I'd like to do this with a single SQL statement if possible, and would like to create the temp table "on the fly" (not create the table in advance).

How can I create a temporary table that is populated with an integer field with values from 1 to 1,000 sequentially?

Using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Tim, this is great - was able to adapt what was in that post to my needs. Sometimes the best answer is someone with better search capabilities! :)

Comment: Just spend 5-10 minutes searching around before posting, you usually find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way uses a recursive CTE:

```
with n as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n < 1000
     )
select n.n
from n
where not exists (select 1 from t where t.userno = n.n)
option (MAXRECURSION 0);
```